# Lowest cost device with HDMI, web browser, and WiFi

Tags: hdmi, computer-building

How can I get a device that can run a web browser connected to a TV? Price is a priority.

So the computer like device should have WiFi, be able to run a browser like Chrome or Firefox, and have an HDMI out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a unit called the [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/), which is the size of a credit card, 700mhz ARM processor, HDMI, ethernet and an SD card all built in to it. It is designed to run Linux, and it can play 1080p video.

It costs roughly £20, which is amazing really for what it is. The first batch has been manufactured and release is imminent.

Alternatively, you could get a Boxee. But that is £180!

Answer (score 0):

Because the TV itself obviously cannot run installed software (if it was one of the newer ones that have built-in apps and basic web browsers you wouldn't be asking this question), you need a device that runs a web browser and outputs to a TV.

Just about any computer and many pseudo-PC devices can do this with the appropriate adapters.

Perhaps the cheapest method would be an appliance such as AppleTV or Google TV or any of the several other such devices out there. They are primarily intended for watching youtube, Hulu, or Netflix, but most of them have rudimentary browsers.

Also, if you have a modern gaming console, you probably have a basic browser app on that. The Wii has a decent browser (no flash or anything more fancy that basic HTML) but it renders OK and works well enough.

So the answer is, once again: It depends.

It depends on what you have right now (old computer handy? this can be REALLY cheap) and what you're really trying to do (need to play netflix, hulu and youtube? you'll need a stronger system).